# How do numpy authors decide whether to put a function in numpy.* vs. numpy.ndarray.*?

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like I'm missing some unifying theme here. There are a couple of observations I'm having trouble contextualizing.

1. flatten() is in numpy.ndarray.*, but flatten() is actually out-of-place, which seems a little odd to me for it to be an object method, rather than a library function.
2. So then, if object methods are allowed to return copies, then why is np.repeat() (out of place) not just an object method in np.ndarray.*?
3. On the other hand, the non-object method numpy.reshape is in-place... this trend seems a bit opposite of what I expected.
4. np.random.randn() takes multiple positional arguments for the dimensions of the array you want to generate, whereas np.zeros takes a single positional argument tuple that contains the dimensions. Is there a reason for this?

I just want to understand the design decisions that led to these choices, so that I'm not repeatedly making silly mistakes in how I call these functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding point #4.  As it says in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html?highlight=randn#numpy.random.randn), "This is a convenience function for users porting code from Matlab".

Comment: Can you provide a definition or description for what you mean by "out-of-place".

Comment: My working definition of "out-of-place" is if I do output = func(input), then make a change to output, that the change is not reflected in input.

Comment: I think you are referring to the question of when to return a view or copy.  There's a nice description of that [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) if it helps.  Maybe provide a couple of examples in your question of behaviour that seems odd to you.

Comment: Many numpy methods have function equivalents.  Look at the function code.  Few functions or methods operate in-place.  Most return a new array object (though it may be a `view`).

Comment: The history of numpy is long, so don't expect perfect unity in style. Keep the reference handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [495]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)      # reshape((3,4)) also                                                         
In [496]: x.flatten?                                                                                   
Docstring:
a.flatten(order='C')
Return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.
```

`ravel` method and function are "equivalent":

```
In [497]: x.ravel?                                                                                     
Docstring:
a.ravel([order])
Return a flattened array.
Signature: np.ravel(a, order='C')
Docstring:
Return a contiguous flattened array.

A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned.  A copy is
```

made only if needed.

By your terminology, `flatten` is `out-of-place`, `ravel` is not.  Or in `numpy's` terms, `ravel` usually produces a `view`, rather than a `copy`.

The actual code for `np.ravel` is:

```
if isinstance(a, np.matrix):
    return asarray(a).ravel(order=order)
else:
    return asanyarray(a).ravel(order=order)
```

If the argument is not an array, it is turned into one.  Then the method is used.

This pattern is quite common.  The function does an `asarray` if needed, and then delegates the action to the method.

`np.reshape` and `x.reshape` follow this pattern.  There is a `x.shape=...` form that is a real `in-place` action.  They return a `view` where possible (they don't change the total number of elements).  This `view` shares data, but has its own `shape` and `strides`.

`resize` is one of the function/method pairs that has significant differences between the two.  We don't use it much.

The `repeat` function is the same as the method.  Because it normally changes the number of elements, `repeat` (both forms) returns a new array, with its own data.  It does not return a `view`.

`sum` is another pair that returns a new array.  It changes the number of elements, so a `view` isn't possible.

As for `randn`, it's docs explains the difference.  Specifying shape as tuple might well the preferred 'standard', but this `randn` behavior is unusual. The suggested alternative for new code `standard_normal` takes the `size` tuple. `reshape` accepts either.

While the normal tuple syntax is `(1,2,3)`, the `()` are actual optional; it's the comma that marks the tuple.  It's required in a 1 element tuple, eg. `(1,)`.  In indexing `x[(1,2)]` and `x[1,2]` are the same, passing a `tuple` to `x.__getitem__`.

Both python and `numpy` have long histories.  Choices made in the past are still with us in one way or other now.  Refining the code is slow; adding features is easier than removing them.